# Disable WordPress Archive Conflict Check

Tags: posts, rewrite-rules, slug

I want to have numerical slugs in WordPress for pages but WordPress doesn't allow this by default in an attempt to preserve the slugs for use by chronological archives. The [`wp_unique_post_slug`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_unique_post_slug) function includes a check which is described as "Prevent new post slugs that could result in URLs that conflict with date archives." Here's the relevant code from line 3812 from `wp-includes/post.php`

```
    // Prevent new post slugs that could result in URLs that conflict with date archives.
    $post = get_post( $post_ID );
    $conflicts_with_date_archive = false;
    if ( 'post' === $post_type && ( ! $post || $post->post_name !== $slug ) && preg_match( '/^[0-9]+$/', $slug ) && $slug_num = intval( $slug ) ) {
        $permastructs   = array_values( array_filter( explode( '/', get_option( 'permalink_structure' ) ) ) );
        $postname_index = array_search( '%postname%', $permastructs );

        /*
         * Potential date clashes are as follows:
         *
         * - Any integer in the first permastruct position could be a year.
         * - An integer between 1 and 12 that follows 'year' conflicts with 'monthnum'.
         * - An integer between 1 and 31 that follows 'monthnum' conflicts with 'day'.
         */
        if ( 0 === $postname_index ||
            ( $postname_index && '%year%' === $permastructs[ $postname_index - 1 ] && 13 > $slug_num ) ||
            ( $postname_index && '%monthnum%' === $permastructs[ $postname_index - 1 ] && 32 > $slug_num )
        ) {
            $conflicts_with_date_archive = true;
        }
    }
```

Commenting out this code should in theory allow slugs like `/example/2019` but WordPress continues to append `-2` to slugs matching the code's regular expression. I can't find anywhere else this check is being done.

There will never be an archive under `/example` so the attempt at protecting users throws out functionality with no benefit.

How can this unwanted behavior be disabled?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89825/discussion-on-question-by-mtcdood-disable-wordpress-archive-conflict-check).

Answer (score 2):

If you read a little further down past that code you are thinking about commenting out, you will see that right before the function is finished it provides a hook for the result:

```
return apply_filters( 'wp_unique_post_slug', $slug, $post_ID, $post_status, $post_type, $post_parent, $original_slug );
```

This means you can override what it is doing to your slugs:

```
add_filter( 'wp_unique_post_slug', 'wpse_328945_unique_post', 11, 6 );
function wpse_328945_unique_post( $slug, $post_ID, $post_status, $post_type, $post_parent, $original_slug ){
    return $original_slug;
}
```

So we are accepting 6 arguments to get the last one, original slug, and then returning the original.

Of course this will completely bypass the unique_slug functionality, and you may not want that. You could add to the function some more checking to see if it was of the type you are trying to preserve, and only return the original if so (otherwise return the $slug variable so as to do nothing).

Comment: This answer does not provide a solution to the identified problem.

Comment: "You cannot delete this question as others have invested time and effort into answering it. For more information, visit the help center." Please delete your answer so I can delete my question.

Comment: No thank you. Your question was how to bypass WordPress' unique post slug check. I researched and provided a solution that does exactly that, using WordPress' built in hook system. It is relevant information that others who have a similar issue in the future may benefit from. Part of asking questions on Stack Exchange and getting free help from volunteers is that you are releasing your question to the Internet. (In fact in posting a question you have granted StackExchange a royalty-free, perpetual license for what you've written.)

Comment: You did not provide a solution that does exactly that. I did and everyone shat on both my question and my answer.

Comment: Just because you don't understand an answer does not mean it's incorrect.